# Socket read()ing into a function that returns pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function, sockets

I have a class called `message`. Here you could find the relevant piece of code:

```
class message
{
    private:
        HeaderType header;
        // Message text
        byte * text;    

    public:
        ~message();
        byte * getText();
...};

/*
 * Destructor
 */
message::~message(){
    if (header.ack == false) free (text);
}

/*
 * getText
 *
 * Returns pointer to text
 */
byte * message::getText(){
    return text;
}
```

I need to read directly into `text`. So, I created the above function `message::getText()` which returns pointer to text. Then, I read into this function. I know, it's wrong. Would anyone please tell me why?

```
read(receive_socket,m.getText(), header.dataSize);
```

Comment: Why you know its wrong? text is a byte pointer and your `getText()` function returns it. Whether it points to a location in memory at the time of the call that remains to be seen as you haven't showed us when and where you are assigning `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is responsible for maintaining that data? I see a `free` (which should be a `delete[]`) but I don't see a `new` anywhere. Are you just returning an uninitialized pointer?

This is a great use-case for `vector`:

```
class message
{
private:
    HeaderType header;
    // Message text
    std::vector<char> text;  
};

std::vector<char>& message::getText() { return text; }
```

Which would be a little better if you just pass in the socket descriptor into your `message` so it can do your `read`:

```
int read(int sd) {
    text.resize(header.dataSize);
    return ::read(sd, &text[0], header.dataSize);
}
```

Comment: However indeed, a linked list is much better. Anyway thank you.